# the session is unavailable because no secret key was set. Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret. Flask/Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, authentication, flask, secret-key

The flask app can login and register all fine on localhost. But this becomes an issue when i push it to heroku. It shows the above mentioned error. Here's the app.py code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, jsonify, url_for, flash
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, asc, desc
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from database_setup import Base, User, BlogPost
from flask import session as login_session
import random
import string
from wtforms import Form, BooleanField, TextField, PasswordField, validators
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt


app = Flask(__name__)


#Connecting to database
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///travellerdata.db')
Base.metadata.bind = engine

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()
```

And ends with...

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.secret_key = 'some secret key'
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Comment: What HTTP server are you using? gunicorn?

Comment: I'm guessing that when your HTTP server is loading your application, `__name__` is not set to `'main'`. Try moving the `app.secret_key = 'some secret key'` to outside the if block.

Comment: I literally just had this problem (though the solution to my problem was different than this).

Comment: I support @mathguy54 's sol'n. BUT On Heroku there is an option to set the secret key through the GUI. If possible you should look into that option as well. Storing a plaintext secret key in source code is not usually a secure move.

Comment: Yes, you should configure the application right after you instantiate app

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have the same issue when I use flask-login to generate a session ID, it works fine when I directly run it but will output error when I use HTTP server. The original code is like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
    app.run()
```

Then I moved `app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)` out of `__name__` and put it under `app = Flask(__name__)` like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

login_manager = flask_login.LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
```

And it works fine now.

Comment: And you just saved me from a heartbreak! Thanks man. Phew! I owe you a drink.

Answer (score 8):

It's likely that when your HTTP server is loading your application, `__name__` is not equal to `'main'`. Try moving the line `app.secret_key = 'some secret key'` outside the if block.

It's not a good idea to put your secret key in source code because if anyone gets it they can malevolently gain access to your system. Try storing it in a file in the application's instance directory ([snippet here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/104/)) or putting it in an environment variable ([explanation here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#development-production)).

Comment: Generate a secret key each time the server starts with

app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

but be sure to have import os at the top of the file.

Answer (score 4):

The exception is raised by the NullSessionInterface session implementation, which is the default session type when you use Flask-Session. That's because you don't ever actually give the SESSION_TYPE configuration to Flask; it is not enough to set it as a global in your module.

This default doesn't make much sense with Flask 0.10; it may have made sense with Flask 0.8 or 0.9, but the current version is used as an error signal. In your case it gives you the wrong error message now.

Set the SESSION_TYPE configuration option to something else. Pick one of redis, memcached, filesystem or mongodb.

Setting it to filesystem is easiest; there is enough default configuration there to have that work without additional dependencies:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.secret_key = 'super secret key'
    app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'

    sess.init_app(app)

app.debug = True
app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I read this on random website after tried a lot a lot of solution but nothing worked the solution was very simple for me i just put
app.secret_key = 'super secret key'
after app = Flask(**name**) directly not in the bottom of the file.

Comment: please fix your answer structure