# Server error on Flask-Pymongo app deployed to Heroku.... what am I missing?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, pymongo

I'll try and provide as much information as possible here. The app works locally just fine. The app is deployed successfully, and I can get to the login screen... but when I log in, I then see the following error:
`Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.`

I apologize for the crazy long post but I wanted to make sure I got everything out there that might be helpful...

My Current file structure:

```
-static
--client side js, css, images etc
-templates
--all my templates
-app.py
-Pipfile
-Pipfile.lock
-Procfile
-requirements.txt
```

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, session, redirect, jsonify, json, flash
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from jinja2 import Template, TemplateNotFound
from bson.json_util import dumps
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import pprint

app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'heroku_fbdc95hs'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://<username>:<password>@ds161529.mlab.com:61529/heroku_fbdc95hs'

mongo = PyMongo(app)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    if 'username' in session:
        return render_template('dashboard.html')

    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/dashboard")
def dashboard():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return render_template('index.html')

    return render_template('dashboard.html')

@app.route("/student/<string:student_id>")
def student(student_id):
    if 'username' not in session:
        return render_template('index.html')

    print (student_id)
    students = mongo.db.students
    current_student = students.find_one({'_id' : ObjectId(student_id)})
    print(current_student)
    return render_template('student.html', current_student=current_student)


@app.route("/find_all")
def find_all():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return render_template('index.html')

    students = mongo.db.students.find()
    return render_template('view-students.html', students=students)

@app.route("/find_ee")
def find_ee():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return render_template('index.html')

    students = mongo.db.students.find({"major" : "B.S. Electrical Engineering" })
    return render_template('view-students.html', students=students)


@app.route("/find_ce")
def find_ce():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return render_template('index.html')

    students = mongo.db.students.find({"major" : "B.S. Computer Engineering" })
    return render_template('view-students.html', students=students)

@app.route("/probation")
def probation():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return render_template('index.html')

    students = mongo.db.students.find({"standing" : "Probation" })
    return render_template('view-students.html', students=students)



@app.route("/find_uid", methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def find_uid():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return render_template('index.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.form['uid-input']
        students = mongo.db.students.find({"student_id" : result })

    return render_template('view-students.html', students=students)

@app.route("/view-students")
def view_students():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return render_template('index.html')

    return render_template('view-students.html')

@app.route("/add-student")
def add_student():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return render_template('index.html')


    return render_template('add-student.html')


@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    users = mongo.db.users
    login_user = users.find_one({'username' : request.form['username']})

    if login_user:
        if request.form['password'] == login_user['password']:
            session['username'] = request.form['username']
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        return 'Invalid username/password combination'
    return 'Invalid username/password combination'

@app.route('/add', methods=['GET','POST'])
def add():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        students = mongo.db.students
        existing_student = students.find_one({'student_id' : request.form['student_id']})

        if existing_student is None:
            students.insert({'first_name' : request.form['first_name'],
                'last_name' : request.form['last_name'],
                'student_id' : request.form['student_id'],
                'major' : request.form['major'],
                'standing' : request.form['standing'],
                'email' : request.form['email'],
                'phone' : request.form['phone'],
                'transfer' : request.form['transfer']})
            flash("Student successfully added!")
            return redirect(url_for('add'))

        flash("A student with that ID already exists!")


    return render_template('add-student.html')


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.clear()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.secret_key = 'mysecret'
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Pipfile:

```
[requires]
python_full_version = "2.7.14"
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT app:app
```

Logs:

```
2018-04-28T02:37:03.799600+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/dashboard" host=studentsrm.herokuapp.com request_id=c303aed1-a45e-4b84-912a-755fc582c0a5 fwd="73.98.161.187" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=2582 protocol=https
2018-04-28T02:37:03.794207+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.151.201.12 - - [28/Apr/2018:02:37:03 +0000] "GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1" 200 2420 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
2018-04-28T02:37:14.577644+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/login" host=studentsrm.herokuapp.com request_id=ae63c35d-d93f-4240-bbdd-10306d31961b fwd="73.98.161.187" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=500 bytes=456 protocol=https
2018-04-28T02:37:14.570254+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-04-28 02:37:14,569] ERROR in app: Exception on /login [POST]
2018-04-28T02:37:14.570268+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-04-28T02:37:14.570274+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
2018-04-28T02:37:14.570275+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2018-04-28T02:37:14.570277+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
2018-04-28T02:37:14.570279+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2018-04-28T02:37:14.570281+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
2018-04-28T02:37:14.570282+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2018-04-28T02:37:14.570284+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
2018-04-28T02:37:14.570286+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2018-04-28T02:37:14.570287+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
2018-04-28T02:37:14.570289+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2018-04-28T02:37:14.570291+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 113, in login
2018-04-28T02:37:14.570293+00:00 app[web.1]:     session['username'] = request.form['username']
2018-04-28T02:37:14.570294+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 350, in __setitem__
2018-04-28T02:37:14.570296+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._get_current_object()[key] = value
2018-04-28T02:37:14.570298+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 130, in _fail
2018-04-28T02:37:14.570299+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise RuntimeError('The session is unavailable because no secret '
2018-04-28T02:37:14.570302+00:00 app[web.1]: RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.
2018-04-28T02:37:14.572619+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.151.201.12 - - [28/Apr/2018:02:37:14 +0000] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 500 291 "https://studentsrm.herokuapp.com/dashboard" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Does this post answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657821/the-session-is-unavailable-because-no-secret-key-was-set-set-the-secret-key-on

Comment: Unfortunately not. Moving the secret key outside of the if statement just provides me with that awful blue-screen of death heroku error:
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

Comment: I take it back... it worked :)

Comment: So, this whole Heroku thing is driving me nuts. I recently just added in flask_mail, updated a couple of my routes. Updated the requirements.txt and re-deployed... back to the same error screen :( .... runs with `heroku local` but not once deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

app.secret_key = "define secret key of your own choice"

I hope this works for you